# Deploy Sharepoint 2010 web parts without a local sharepoint instance?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to deploy Sharepoint 2010 web parts without a local sharepoint instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the web interface to do this. Upload the solution and deploy it via the central administration console.

If you are looking at automating it, Its not an easy task but theoretically you can open a remote powershell session and use powershell to deploy a solution from a shared/mapped folder in your server. Never did this so not sure.

Comment: Thanks any howto on upload a solution and to where? Thank you :)

Comment: http://sharepointfoundation2010.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/how-to-deploy-solution-wsp-from.html

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are using Visual Studio 2012 you can publish to a SharePoint Sandboxed Solution on a remote SharePoint server. you can find more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370987.aspx